# How can I filter a SQL query by all matching values or all values and null values

Tags: sql-server

This is my query and it is not returning null values

```
SELECT St.Station
FROM Stations as st

where ((Station = CASE 
    WHEN @Station = N'*' 
    THEN Station 
    ELSE @Station END)
  OR (Station = CASE 
     WHEN @Station = N'*' 
     THEN null
     ELSE @Station END))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT St.Station
FROM Stations as st
WHERE Station = @Station OR @Station = N'*'
```

If you pass `'*'` then `@Station = N'*'` will evaluate to true and will select all row, else it will filter by the value of `@Station` variable.

Comment: What i need to do is: if @Station = 'Value' then return all matching rows else if Station = N'*' return all values including nulls

Comment: Yes, my query does exactly what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

NULL values cannot be compared with = operator since they are not equal to anything, even to another NULL. You need to use `IS NULL` for that comparison.

You can simply compare if the given parameter is * or is there a need to compare, like

```
@station=N'*' or station=@station
```

Comment: How would you query where by a value or is null? What i have so far is at the top of the thread.

Comment: I would do as I wrote. If the parameter is *, you don't have to check for anything else. If it's not, check the column

Comment: Thanks, (at)station=N'*' or station=(at)station returns all values including nulls but i want to put this in a conditional where statement  'WHERE Station = CASE WHEN @Station = N'*' THEN N'*' ELSE (at)Station END' so that if (at)Station has a value other than N'*' then that value is returned else all values including null are returned

Comment: @user3592986 what condition should it be in?

Comment: Thanks, I used a mixture of your answer and what i already have

Answer (score 0):

'where (Station = CASE WHEN @Station <> N'*' THEN @Station END
        or @Station = case when @Station = N'*' Then N'*' END)'